# c++ initialize template class constructor

Tags: c++

How do I initialize pointer class B `foo` inside class A? I am new to C++.

Header.h

```
namespace Core
{
    enum type
    {
        Left, Right
    };

    template<type t>
    class B
    {
    public:
        B(int i);
    private:
        type dir;
        int b = 12;
    };

    class A
    {
    public:
        B<Left> *foo;
    };
}
```

Source.cpp

```
namespace Core
{
    template<type t>
    B<t>::B(int i)
    {
        dir = t;
        b = i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Core::A *a = new Core::A;
    a->foo = new Core::B<Core::Left>(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Source.cpp` needs a `#include "Header.h"` statement, and `Header.h` needs a header guard.

Also, you need to move the implemention of `B`'s constructor into the header file. See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/).

Try this:

Header.h:

```
#ifndef HeaderH
#define HeaderH

namespace Core
{
    enum type
    {
        Left, Right
    };

    template<type t>
    class B
    {
    public:
        B(int i);
    private:
        type dir;
        int b = 12;
    };

    class A
    {
    public:
        B<Left> *foo;
    };

    template<type t>
    B<t>::B(int i)
    {
        dir = t;
        b = i;
    }
}

#endif
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
    Core::A *a = new Core::A;
    a->foo = new Core::B<Core::Left>(10);
    //...
    delete a->foo;
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

I would suggest taking it a step further by inlining `B`'s constructor and giving `A` a constructor to initialize `foo`:

Header.h:

```
#ifndef HeaderH
#define HeaderH

namespace Core
{
    enum type
    {
        Left, Right
    };

    template<type t>
    class B
    {
    public:
        B(int i)
        {
            dir = t;
            b = i;
        }

    private:
        type dir;
        int b = 12;
    };

    class A
    {
    public:
        B<Left> *foo;

        A(int i = 0)
            : foo(new B<Left>(i))
        {
        }

        ~A()
        {
            delete foo;
        }
    };
}

#endif
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
    Core::A *a = new Core::A(10);
    //... 
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> How do I initialize pointer class B foo inside class A?

#### Option 1

Construct a `B<Left>` with an assumed value.

```
class A
{
   public:
    B<Left> *foo = new B<Left>(0);
};
```

#### Option 2

Add a constructor of `A` that accepts an `int` that can be used to construct a `B<Left>` .

```
class A
{
   public:
      A(int i) : foo(new B<Left>(i)) {}
    B<Left> *foo;
};
```

#### Word of caution

Before you down too far into using pointers to objects in your classes, consider the following:

1. [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)
2. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory, specially `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`.